# Objects change position in a frame but their infos about location don't change

Tags: animation, objects, transforms, path

I want to make a video of about 1200 frame of a camera moving along a path inside a house, but when I go to frame 1 there are two objects that are not in the position they should be and I don't know why. If I move to frame 37, they are in the correct position and from that frame they stay there, but before frame 37 they change their correct location (I don't why this is happening because I've never animated them).
I've thought about copy the location they have at frame 37 in frame 1 and so on, but when I go to the location informations to change them in frame 1, they are the same I have at frame 37, even if they're not in the same position!
Is there a way to fix this? For now I've just modify the frames that have to be animated to be from 37 to 1237, but I would like to understand why it's doing like this.

Comment: Have you a keyframe for those objects on frame 1? you could try to delete the keyframe, or simply update it (go to frame 1, and insert the keyframe again)